# Mostrar 2 decimales de un número en formato string

Tags: c#

Tengo un número en una variable de tipo `string`.

Si ese número no tiene decimales o solo un decimal necesito convertirlo a un numero con 2 decimales, en donde el decimal que falte sea rellenado por el `0`.

Ejemplo:

- Si numero = `15`  la variable debe contener `15,00`
- Si numero = `15.1` la variable debe contener `15,10`
- Si numero = `15.22` la variable debe contener `15,22`

Lo he intentado con:

```
String.Format("{0:N2}", "15")
```

Pero me muestra `15`.

Comment: Mi pregunta es, porque tienes almacenado un valor numérico así en una variable string? Si la tuvieras declarada de tipo integer no seria mas fácil para ti manipular el dato? Aun mas fácil, si tu variable fuera de tipo float no tendrías que formatear ni parsear nada, solo indicar la cantidad de decimales que quieres.

Comment: @ErnestoRincon al mostrar en pantalla, sin importar como la tiene, SIEMPRE tiene que formatear... asi que tu comentario no tiene mucho sentido...

Comment: @gbianchi y no puede simplemente hacer un ToString() cuando ya tenga su variable con el formato que quiere?

Comment: Yo lo pasaría a su correspondiente tipo real y luego lo formatearía con `ToString`. Algo como `decimal.Parse("15").ToString("#0.00")`

Comment: Con decimal.Parse("15").ToString("#0.00") parece que me sirve. No se si hay otra solucion mejor

Comment: Es que tu problema viene por otro lado.. String esta tratando de formatear a numero una cadena, no un numero ;)... de ahi, que tangas que pasarlo a numero, y luego a cadena... Lo que te decian arriba de tenerlo en una variable numerica es valido, no asi la parte del formateo, porque el formateo hay que hacerlo siempre....

Comment: Es un string porque el numero se me devuelve mediante un Json en string. Me quedo con la solucion que me dio @Pikoh

Comment: Pero ese detalle del JSON no lo habías mencionado en tu pregunta. Tienes que ser lo mas especifico posible y brindar toda la información que puedas.

Comment: @ErnestoRincon ya mencione que la variable de entrada era un numero metido en un string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo veo 2 preguntas, una es la conversión de `string` a `decimal`, y la otra es formatear ese `decimal`

1.- Para convertir de `string` a `decimal` tienes al menos 3 buenas opciones, todas ellas funcionan bien para los casos "correctos", ejemplo `50.44` y la diferencias entre ellas va en lo casos de borde

- `decimal.Parse`: Arroja una excepción si no puede convertir (errores de formato y `null`)
- `decimal.TryParse`: Retorna `true` cuando convierte y `false` en caso contrario
- `Convert.ToDecimal`: Un valor `null` lo convierte a cero

El problema al recibir un valor con decimales como `string` desde una fuente externa es la `Culture`, es decir, el típico problema del punto y la coma, que por ejemplo en mi país usamos la coma como separador decimal y el punto como separador de miles, y otros lo hacen a la inversa, y esto es lo que pasa cuando convertirnos:

```
decimal.Parse("1000,2") //Imprime: 1000,2
decimal.Parse("1000.2") //Imprime: 10002
```

Si te fijas en el último caso se hace caso omiso al punto y retorna `10002` (como si el punto no existiera). Al NO arrojar alguna excepción, esto presenta un riesgo, porque puedes (por ejemplo) estar guardando en tu base de datos un número totalmente incorrecto y no te llegas a enterar nunca (porque no hay excepción!)

Otro problema típico es tener una `cuture` distinta en el computador que desarrollas y otra en el que publicas.

Para solventar estos problemas, te recomiendo que verifiques cual es la `culture` que usa el sistema que provee el JSON y la uses cada vez que conviertes. Por ejemplo digamos que está en ingles de Estados Unidos, tu tendrías que hacer algo como esto:

```
decimal.Parse("1000.2",CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"))
```

---

2.- Para el tema de mostrar 2 decimales, puedes usar los formatos preestablecidos o usar uno "customizado". Para ambos casos, puedes establecer separador de miles o no

Formatos preestablecidos `F` y `N`

```
decimal numero = 1000.2m;
Console.WriteLine(numero.ToString("F2")); //1000,20
Console.WriteLine(numero.ToString("N2")); //1.000,20
```

El primero NO utiliza separadores de miles, mientras el segundo si lo hace.

Luego tienes un formato `customizado`

```
Console.WriteLine(numero.ToString("#0.00")); //1000,20
Console.WriteLine(numero.ToString("#0,000.00")); //1.000,20
```

Igualmente que el caso anterior, el primero NO utiliza separadores de miles, mientras el segundo si lo hace.

```js
public static class Ext
{
    public static string ToDecimal(this string str, string formato = "N2", string cultura = "es-US") {
        if(decimal.TryParse(str, out decimal d))
        { 
            return d.ToString(formato, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(cultura));
        }

        //retornar algo cuando no ha podido convertir
        //Sugerencias:

        //throw new FormatException();
        //return "0";
        //return str;
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: En realidad era una pregunta porque no queria convertir de string a decimal sino que la salida fuera otro  numero dentro de un string pero con el formato de 2 decimales. Que para ello se tuviera que convertir a decimal y luego a string es uno de los metodos. Pudiera ser que hubiera un tipo de solucion que no hiciera falta convertir a decimal. Pero bien con esta solucion ya me vale

Comment: @Popularfan tal vez puedas lograrlo escribiendo tu propia función de formato. Cuando tenga algo de tiempo te doy un ejemplo.

Comment: @Mateo No hace falta, la solucion que me dieron ya es buena. Gracias

Comment: @Popularfan Siempre puedes crear un método de extensión, abajo de mi respuesta si presionas `Mostrar fragmento de código` he puesto un ejemplo. Luego para usarlo basta hacer `"12.3".ToDecimal();`